# How to capture form handler views in pardot?

Tags: salesforce-marketing-cloud, pardot

I am using pardot form handlers in my website.
Form handlers does not have a way to record the views out of the box.
Is there any workaround through which we can get the views recorded on the form handlers?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to "view" with a form handler, that's why there is nothing tracked.

A Pardot Form has both the Front-End and Back-End of a web form. The Front-End is what Pardot can track as a view.

A Pardot Form Handler has only the Back-End of a web form, with the website having the Front-End built with whatever tech desired.

You would need to rely on the page being viewed to get a count of how many people (likely) saw the Form (which is then supported by a Form Handler upon submission).